# How to set class objects from vector of string in c++

Tags: c++, csv, vector, strsplit

These are the data in my Login.csv file:

> ID,Name,Password,Gender
>
> 1,Liam,1234,M
>
> 2,Janice,0000,F

So probably I'll use class & objects to create login details, and write it into the file. After that I will split the csv from file into a vector of strings, from there how do I load back the details to objects of class.

This is my code of splitting the csv from file:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    string line;
    ifstream fin("users.csv");

    while (getline(fin, line)){
        vector<string> token;
        split(line, ',', token);

        for (int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++){
            cout << token[i] << " ";

            //////////// <<here>>
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void split(const string& s, char c, vector<string>& v) {

    string::size_type i = 0;
    string::size_type j = s.find(c);

    while (j != string::npos) {
        v.push_back(s.substr(i, j - i));
        i = ++j;
        j = s.find(c, j);

        if (j == string::npos)
            v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
    }
}
```

I was thinking how can I set the splitted strings from the string vector to a vector of objects, something like this: (to put in the << here >> section i commented in above)

```
vector<Login>loginVector;

//all the objects below should set from string vector (token)
loginVector[i].setID(); //i=0, id=1, name=Liam, password=1234, gender=M
loginVector[i].setName();
loginVector[i].setPassword();
loginVector[i].setGender();

loginVector[i].setID(); //i=1, id=2, name=Janice, password=0000, gender=M
loginVector[i].setName();
loginVector[i].setPassword();
loginVector[i].setGender();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try searching at all? There are 100s of questions about parsing CSVs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: To be fair the discussion there and all the answers seem to involve `boost` which is a bit overkill for a simple CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your `Login` object and populate it in the loop.

```
struct Login {
    enum Gender {
        Male,
        Female
    };

    int Id;
    std::string Name;
    std::string Password;

    /* you should probably use a constructor */
};

/* to construct your vector */

int I = 0;
while(I < token.size()) {
    /* in your iterator */
    Login& LO = loginVector.emplace_back(Login{});

    LO.Id = std::stoi(token[++I]);
    LO.Name = token[++I];

    /* etc...*/
}
```

Note that this assumes your CSV is well formed, up to you to implement all the checking and make sure you handle corner cases like possible errors from `stoi`, blank rows or missing columns.

Also, don't do `system("pause");`, you're executing a shell to sleep for you, which has massive overhead compared to just using `sleep` which does literally the same thing except in a far more direct way.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would implement this by adding an [extraction operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for your class.
You'll have to `friend` the extraction operator because it must be defined externally to your class, since it's actually operating on the `istream` and not on your class, so something like this should be defined in your class:

```
friend istream& operator>> (istream& lhs, Login& rhs);
```

Depending on how your variables are named your extraction operator should look something like this:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& lhs, Login& rhs) {
    char gender;

    lhs >> rhs.id;
    lhs.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',');
    getline(lhs, rhs.name, ',');
    getline(lhs, rhs.password, ',');
    lhs >> ws;
    lhs.get(gender);
    rhs.isMale = gender == 'm' || gender == 'M';

    return lhs;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/fyqy07)